# Spring Mono<User> as constructor param - how to "cache" object

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, project-reactor

I'm drawing a blank on how to do this in project reactor with Spring Boot:

```
class BakerUserDetails(val bakerUser: Mono<BakerUser>): UserDetails {
    override fun getPassword(): String {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
        // return ???.password
    }

    override fun getUsername(): String {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
        // return ???.username
    }

}
```

How do I make this work? Do I just put `bakerUser.block().password` and `bakerUser.block().username` and all, or is there a better way to implement these methods?

Currently, I'm doing something like this but it seems strange:

```
    private var _user: BakerUser? = null
    private var user: BakerUser? = null
    get() {
        if(_user == null){
            _user = bakerUser.block()
        }
        return _user
    }

override fun getAuthorities(): MutableCollection<out GrantedAuthority> {
        return mutableSetOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"))
    }

    override fun getPassword(): String {
        return user!!.password!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not well versed at Kotlin, but i can tell you that you should not pass in a `Mono`to the `UserDetails` object.

A `Mono<T>` is sort of like a future/promise. Which means that there is nothing in it. So if you want something out of it, you either `block` which means we wait, until there is something in it, or we subscribe, which basically means we wait `async` until there is something in it. Which can be bad. Think of it like starting a job on the side. What happens if you start a job and you quit the program, well the job would not be executed.

Or you do something threaded, and the program returns/exits, well main thread dies, all threads die, and nothing happend.

We usually in the reactive world talk about `Publishers` and `Consumers`. So a `Flux/Mono` is a `Publisher` and you then declare a `pipeline`for what to happen when something is resolved. And to kick off the process the `consumer`needs to `subscribe` to the `producer`.

Usually in a server world, this means that the webpage, that does the request, is the `consumer` and it `subscribes` to the server which in this case is the `publisher`.

So what im getting at, is that you, should almost never `subscribe` in your application, unless, your application is the one that starts the consumption. For instance you have a cron job in your server that consumes another server etc.

lets look at your problem:

You have not posted your code so im going to do some guesswork here, but im guessing you are getting a user from a database.

```
public Mono<BakerUserDetails> loadUserByUsername(String username) {

    Mono<user> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    // Here we declare our pipline, flatMap will map one object to another async
    Mono<BakerUserDetails> bakerUser = user.flatMap(user -> Mono.just(new BakerUserDetails(user));
    return bakerUser;
}
```

i wrote this without a compiler from the top of my head.

So dont pass in the `Mono<T>` do your transformations using different operators like `map` or `flatMap` etc. And dont subscribe in your application unless your server is the final consumer.

Comment: Thanks - my issue is that I need to get a mono and return an object (not a mono) so I guess I need to block in my constructor. This is Spring security so I can't really change the return type...

Comment: I cant address this statement unless you post more of your code. Either you are writing a webflux application, then you teturn a mono, or you write a blocking application, then you block and return a concrete value. There is no middle ground. What i posted is non blocking webflux code. You have posted way too little context for me to give you a better answer.

Comment: the `flatMap` is what I needed, that does it.